# Families of polynomials given by tuples of binary forms with finitely many reducible members

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $G_1, \cdots, G_n \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ be binary forms, and put $\mathbf{G} = (G_1, \cdots, G_n)$. Consider the family of monic polynomials

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{F}_\mathbf{G} = \{x^n + G_1(p,q) x^{n-1} + \cdots + G_n(p,q) : p, q \in \mathbb{Z}, \gcd(p,q) = 1\}.$$

Are there any examples of families as above, for some choice of $\mathbf{G}$, where one can show that every member of $\mathcal{F}_\mathbf{G}$ is irreducible? Certainly for most choices of $\mathbf{G}$ the *generic* element of $\mathcal{F}_\mathbf{G}$ is irreducible, and in fact has Galois group isomorphic to $S_n$, by Hilbert's irreducibility theorem. I am interested in cases and techniques which enables on to show that *all but finitely many* members in the family are irreducible.